# How can I hide a specific category from the Featured Products and the category nav in Bigcartel

Tags: variables, categories, bigcartel

I've set up a Bigcartel site using the Luna theme. My client has been selling furniture. He now wants to also have artist exhibitions and sell that work on his site. The problem is he doesn't want the two groups mixed together.

I'd like to make categories that will be hidden from the Featured Products list and the category navigation. We will then just link to each artist's category page manually from a custom page called "exhibitions".

It seems like there should be a simple variable that will just hide category LINKS but not the actual category pages.

I hope this made sense. thanks so much. I'm also open to a different way of solving this problem, but this seemed like the way to go.

here is the homepage... with the featured products on it and the category navigation also: http://www.otherspacela.com/products

Dylan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To hide specific categories from your navigation, you'll want to write an `if` statement...

```
{% if category.permalink != 'seating' and category.permalink != 'lighting' %}

{% endif %}
```

This will hide the Seating and Lighting categories. To implement this, find the following code (near the top of your Furnishings page)

```
<ul>
  <li class="{% if page.full_url contains '/products' %}selected{% endif %}"><a href="/products">All</a></li>    
  {% for category in categories.active %}
  <li class="page {% if page.full_url contains category.url %}selected{% endif %}">{{ category | link_to }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Modify the 4th line of that code like so, and you'll be all set:

```
<ul>
  <li class="{% if page.full_url contains '/products' %}selected{% endif %}"><a href="/products">All</a></li>    
  {% for category in categories.active %}
    {% if category.permalink != 'seating' and category.permalink != 'lighting' %}
      <li class="page {% if page.full_url contains category.url %}selected{% endif %}">{{ category | link_to }}</li>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```